# Ada: Importing the inequality operator "/="

Tags: import, package, operator-overloading, ada, inequality

I don't want to `use` an entire package, but I do want to import a few features, such as the `"/="` operator. I know that `renames` allows me to do this with most functions, but with the inequality operator I get the error, `explicit definition of inequality not allowed`. How do I import this operator without raising the error?

```
package Integer_Maps is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
(
 Key_Type => Integer,
 Element_Type => Integer
);

-- the next line fails!
function "/=" ( Left, Right: Integer_Maps.Cursor ) return Boolean
   renames Integer_Maps."/=";
```

Comment: "Explicit overloading of the inequality operator is not allowed", [LRM83 6.7](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-06-07.html) para 4.

Comment: @SimonWright I cited the 2012 LRM 6.6 in my answer below, but I do find it interesting that they removed/rephrased that sentence in one of the subsequent LRM's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't! not directly, at any rate. Renaming the equality operator `"="`, and you get inequality for free.

```
-- this line succeeds!
function "=" ( Left, Right: Integer_Maps.Cursor ) return Boolean
   renames Integer_Maps."=";
```

This is similar to overriding the operators. See [ARM 6.6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-6.html), in particular **Static Semantics**.

Comment: You could also do a `use type Integer_Maps.Cursor;`

Comment: @egilhh Thanks; I was not aware of that, but if I'm using several containers, will that cause problems with the names?

Comment: no, there should be no problems with the names. Since you weren't aware of `use type`, I've submitted an answer about it (and `use all type`)

Answer (score 4):

You could do a `use type Integer_Maps.Cursor;` which gives visibility of the operators on the type.

For the container cursors, it might also be practical to do a `use all type Integer_Maps.Cursor;` which gives visibility of all the primitive operations on the type, like `Key` and `Element`.

I usually put `use type` and `use all type` clauses in the innermost enclosing scope (i.e. inside subprograms) where they're needed, like so:

```ada
   procedure Foo is
       use all type Integer_Maps.Cursor; 
   begin
       for Cursor in My_Map.Iterate loop
          Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
            (Integer'Image(Key(Cursor)) & " ->" & Integer'Image(Element(Cursor)));
       end loop;
   end Foo;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this yesterday but gnat didn't like it with two different `Cursor` types in the global scope. I'll try this again later today when I'm at home.